# How do I split up my project into CMake modules that can find eachother?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a project with components (e.g. Dependency) that are very modular,

```
Project
-Dependency
--Include
--Src
--CMakeLists.txt
-Main
--main.cpp
--CMakeLists.txt
CMakeLists.txt
```

Right now, I use `target_link_libraries()` and `include_directories()` in my main CMakeLists.txt with explicit relative paths to use them.

I want to turn my dependencies into packages/modules/components/libraries/**some-things** that are self-contained, so I can remove the explicit paths.

I don't want to install them. They will remain in the build tree. I want to, e.g. move the entire Dependency folder without breaking anything, or copy the folder into another project and have it work with just a `find_package()` call.

--

I have tried

```
target_include_directories(Dependency PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>)
target_link_libraries(Dependency PUBLIC *Sub-dependencies*)
```

and

```
export(TARGETS Dependency FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_modules/DependencyConfig.cmake")
```

in the Dependency CMakeLists.txt, based on:

https://rix0r.nl/blog/2015/08/13/cmake-guide/ &
https://pabloariasal.github.io/2018/02/19/its-time-to-do-cmake-right/

But `find_package()` still fails.

--

How do I export an interface so that CMake can automatically configure dependencies between modules in the same build tree?

Comment: Sebf, could you please consider undeleting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77656409/85371)? I had just written up a nicer solution that you will definitely like. (And you can tell I took more than 20 minutes to do it, as I didn't notice the deletion)

Comment: @sehe OK, I thought I found a dumb mistake, but if you have a good answer then it would be great to see it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `target_include_directories`, then the dependent targets for that target can have the includes as well, depending on the PUBLIC/PRIVATE setting.

Same as `target_link_directories` which propagates the libraries to dependent targets.

You never need the path to the libraries, as CMake *should* take care of that for you. If it doesn't, it's probably a bug.